# Two identical monitors, but one of them showing wrong list of available resolutions when I plug them into my Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, display, multiple-monitors, resolution, troubleshooting

I'm using a Macbook Pro laptop at work.  Here are the specs:

```
MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018)
MacOS Catalina v10.15.2
2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
16 GB 2400 MHz DDR4
Radeon Pro 560X 4 GB; Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB
```

I am also using two of these monitors: https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/UM.CE7AA.001

I am plugging them into my laptop using 2 DisplayPort -> USB-C cables. For whatever reason, every single morning when I come into the office and plug in my monitors, one of them defaults to the correct resolution (3440x1440) @ 100Hz, and the other goes to 1080p @ 60Hz.

Here's where the annoyance is: the monitor that defaults to a lower resolution physically is not being allowed to change to the proper resolution. The correct resolutions aren't even appearing in the displays settings.

Here's the available resolutions on the currently correct monitor (left) and the currently incorrect monitor (right):
[available resolutions on my monitors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXOCE.png)

**I am also aware of the "trick" where you hold the option key while clicking the scaled resolutions** to view "all available resolutions for the monitor", but it's still capped at 1080p when I do that.

I have tried using software like [EasyRes](http://easyresapp.com/) and [SwitchResX](https://www.madrau.com/) to change to resolutions not shown in the Displays Preferences pane, but even those software show different available resolutions for my two monitors while one of them is acting up.

It is important to note that after 20-45 minutes I'm usually able to get both monitors working at their proper resolutions, but the only way I can get this to happen is to sit at my desk unplugging and replugging in my monitors, sleeping and waking my mac, and changing usb ports around until it just seems to randomly work one time.

How can I consistently and quickly resolve this issue going forward?

Comment: Are the USB-C to DisplayPort adapters identical? Can you edit your question to link to the product(s) you're using for that? I find that it's critical to use high quality adapters that have all the certifications from the standards groups involved. There's a lot of half-broken crap out there.

Comment: This seems like the typical bandwidth issue. The MacBook pro only uses the UHD 630 for USB-C->DP1.4 . And the max res is 4096x2304 @ 60 Hz for any three monitor. You're at 100hz each and close to the res limit...